# Upgrade 18R1 to 19R2 Failed to resolve type reference

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization package in 18R1 and I am trying to upgrade to 19R2.  During the upgrade I get a compilation error:

```
Validating Binary Files
LingoEDI.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.SM.SiteMapMaint declared in PX.Data, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e
LingoEDI.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Objects.Common.PXOrderedSelect`5 declared in 
PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Fixed binding: Document from PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry
Fixed binding: Transactions from PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry
Fixed binding: Adjustments from PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry
Fixed binding: ARInvoice_DocType_RefNbr from PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry
```

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?  How do I trace it back to the offending code?  The project was compiled in Studio 2017 .NET 4.7.1 C# 6.

***Follow-up***
After compiling with 19R2, I am getting compile errors trying to delete site map entries via a plugin. It appears that SiteMapMaint has been removed. Do you know how to remove site map entries in 19R2?

Code:

```
//Site map graph
SiteMapMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SiteMapMaint>();

//Check all the site maps for this screen
foreach (SiteMap smap in PXSelect<SiteMap, Where<SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<SiteMap.screenID>>>>
    .Select(graph, screenID))
{
    parentDescription = "";
    SiteMap siteMapParent = PXSelect<SiteMap, Where<SiteMap.nodeID, Equal<Required<SiteMap.nodeID>>>>
    .Select(graph, smap.ParentID);

    //Do not delete hidden site map entries
    if (siteMapParent != null)
    {
        parentDescription = siteMapParent.ScreenID + siteMapParent.Title;
        if (siteMapParent.ScreenID == "HD000000")
        {
            //this.WriteLog(string.Format("Site map '{0}' is hidden ", screenID));
            continue;
        }
    }

    //Remove site map entry from visible entry
    if (smap != null)
    {
        graph.Caches[typeof(SiteMap)].PersistDeleted(smap);
        this.WriteLog(string.Format("Site map '{0}' removed. '{1}' ", smap.Title, parentDescription));
    }
}
return;
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'   LingoEDI    C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\18R10816_19R20170\App_Data\Projects\LingoEDI\LingoEDI\EDIDataSetup.cs  138 Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SiteMapMaint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  LingoEDI    C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\18R10816_19R20170\App_Data\Projects\LingoEDI\LingoEDI\EDIDataSetup.cs  114 Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SiteMapMaint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  LingoEDI    C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\18R10816_19R20170\App_Data\Projects\LingoEDI\LingoEDI\EDIDataSetup.cs  114 Active
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it was compiled against the target Acumatica version.

Right click on the C# project in solution explorer pane, select `Unload Project` option.
Right click on the C# project in solution explorer pane, select `Edit XYZ.csproj`.

In the project definition, make sure all PX assembly paths point to the Bin folder of the website where the customization will be deployed.

```
<Reference Include="PX.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\AcumaticaSites\TargetWebsite\Bin\PX.Common.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PX.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\AcumaticaSites\TargetWebsite\Bin\PX.Data.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\AcumaticaSites\TargetWebsite\Bin\PX.Objects.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Right click on the C# project in solution explorer pane, select `Reload Project` option.

Try to compile the project, it will likely fail because `PXOrderedSelect` type was moved to a different namespace or assembly. Fix the compilation error by adding the required using clause then recompile and update the customization project with the new DLL file.

Comment: I have some questions on how to do this. I have always put my source under the projects folder using the default location of the extension library from the customization project screen.  Since I can't upgrade the project without compiling it and I can't setup my normal environment without upgrading I must be doing it differently than normal.  What is the best way to have the source in a static folder and then be able to compile in different versions? I have always struggled with this.

Comment: You can put the source code anywhere. It doesn't matter if the references path are absolute instead of relative. To compile for a specific Acumatica version you need to change the reference path for Acumatica assembly in the Visual Studio project. I can't tell where you installed the website so you need to figure out that path, you can use Acumatica wizard or IIS to locate it. Once the path is known you follow the procedure in my answer to change the path in HintPath xml element of the project to update the project references.

Comment: Please see update above regarding sitemap item delete

Comment: That's a good sign, it means the Acumatica reference were properly updated in the C# project. SitemapMaint was moved to PX.SiteMap assembly so you will need to add PX.SiteMap.DLL reference to your project and then you can access it with PX.SiteMap.Graph.SiteMapMaint.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I got it compiled clean.  Now I have to setup the instance to upgrade.  One other question, is there any way to install multiple versions of Acumatica on one computer or do I need to uninstall and reinstall to change the version?

Comment: Kinda yes and no. It's only possible to use multiple version at the same without installing them. Instead of installing them you can extract the content of the MSI setup package to a directory and you can then run AcumaticaConfig.exe wizard from there without having installed the program in Windows. This command will extract the content of the setup package: msiexec.exe /a "C:\Downloads\AcumaticaERPInstall.msi" /qb targetdir="C:\InstallDirectory"

Comment: I have been working with this off and on and I am running into problems.  I can compile it clean, but then it won't load.  I am thinking I need to unpublish the project, upgrade the site, then recompile the project and publish.  Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by it won't load? If you have runtime errors the most likely explanation is that you're not compiling against the correct version.